# Silent UI automation

Tags: c#, testing, ui-automation

Is there a tool for .NET (either free or commercial) which can execute UI automation in a silent manner? Eg. go to control panel and so something, without it being shown on the logged on user's session.

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing in Control Panel that you should ever do without the user's knowledge and consent.

Comment: control panel was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you're looking to do. Some things cannot be done due to intentional developer-made windows limitations (for anti-spam and security reasons).

Check out the APIs and the command line options to see if they can do what you're looking for.

You can execute command line commands from .Net code silently, but that might not always do what you need.